# Object oriented design for three types which two are exactly the same

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I have three types of Persons:

```
    Class Normal
{
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    int Age { get; set; }
}

    Class Better
{
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    int Age { get; set; }
}

    Class Best
{
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    int Age { get; set; }
    string Address { get; set; }
    int Score { get; set; }
}
```

what is the best way to put them in one list?
I myself came up with:

```
 public enum PersonType
{
    Normal = 0,
    Better = 1,
    Best  = 2
}

public interface IPerson
{
    PassengerType Type { get; set; }
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    int Age { get; set; }
}
```

And then

```
public class Person:IPerson
{
    public PassengerType Type { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

which I can use it for both Normal and Better and I can make distiction by type and

```
public class Best:IPerson
{
    public PassengerType Type { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
}
```

and eventually: List ....

Is this a good design? what if a 'best' instance is created, but type is set to Normal. would it be a bad design?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Which programming language do you use?

Comment: C# is the language of my choice

Answer (score 1):

In general comparing class type will be enough. Your code may look something like this:

```
public class BasePerson
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class NormalPerson : BasePerson
{   
}

public class BetterPerson : BasePerson
{    
}

public class BestPerson : BasePerson
{
    string Address { get; set; }
    int Score { get; set; }
}
```

And list:

```
IList<BasePerson> list = new List<BasePerson>();
list.Add(new NormalPerson());
list.Add(new BetterPerson());
list.Add(new BestPerson());
```

Finally, using `GetType()` and `typeof()` methods you can always determine the real type that `BasePerson` variable reference to

```
BasePerson person = new NormalPerson();
var isNormalPerson = person.GetType() == typeof(NormalPerson);
// isNormalPerson is true
var isBestPerson = person.GetType() == typeof(BestPerson);
// isBestPerson is false
```

If you need to use `PersonType` enum, you may modify classes in this way:

```
public abstract class BasePerson
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public abstract PersonType Type { get; }
}

public class NormalPerson : BasePerson
{
   public override PersonType Type
   {
      get { return PersonType.Normal; }
   }
}

public class BetterPerson : BasePerson
{
   public override PersonType PersonType
   {
      get { return PersonType.Better; }
   }
}

...
```